# checkbox return only false even it is checked in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I submit the form while change dropdown option.After submit the form i redirect in to same page.
I submit the form Using below function:

```
function submitform(){
    //Below variables are checkbox value
    var addresscheck = $('#addressmatchedCheck').is(':checked');
    var rcnumbercheck =  $('#rcnumbermatched').is(':checked');
    var phonenumbercheck = $('#phonenumbercheck').is(':checked');
    var idproofcheck = $('#idproofcheck').is(':checked');
    var guarantoraddresscheck = $('#guarantoraddressmatchedCheck').is(':checked');
    var guarantoridcheck = $('#guarantoridproofcheck').is(':checked');
    var guarantorrelationcheck = $('#guarantorrelationshipCheck').is(':checked');
    if( addresscheck &  rcnumbercheck & phonenumbercheck & idproofcheck  & guarantoraddresscheck & guarantoridcheck & guarantorrelationcheck) {
                $('#statusid').val(1);
                alert($('#statusid').val() + "if");
    }
    else{
        $('#statusid').val(2);
        alert($('#statusid').val() + "else");
    }
    $('#fieldVerificationFormID').attr('method', 'POST'); 
    $('#fieldVerificationFormID').attr('action', '/mfi/api/1.0/client/ci/groups/member/fieldverification/insert');
    $('#fieldVerificationFormID').submit();
}
```

My problem is checkbox return only false even it is checked?
First time i.e before form submit it works exactly.Issue is after form submission.
can anyone sove my issue?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: post some examples on JSFiddle

Comment: actually i am using jade for UI design so i am not able to demonstrate in JSFiddle

Comment: upload anywhere else so we could test it?

Comment: Which jade are you talking about? Is the design relevant to this problem? Can't you take your (generated) HTML together with this code and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: You mean after you submit the form it goes back to unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. I have a function that extends JQuery with an isChecked() function. I made this ages ago before the :checked was available in the selectors. But it's pretty bulletproof.

```
jQuery.fn.isChecked = function() {
    var isChecked = false;
    this.each(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            isChecked = true;
            return;
        }
    });
    return isChecked;
}

function check() {
    var addressCheck = $('#addressmatchedCheck').isChecked();
}
```

Comment: dude you can always to do jQuery("selector").is(":checked"), Why do u need such complex methods

Comment: This code was written before :checked was available. I thought that if the OP couldn't get it working. He could at least have an alternative (thanks for the downvote mate)

Comment: :checked is availble since version 1.0, I did not down vote by the way :)

Comment: OK no worries. We'll see how the OP goes. Didn't realise :checked has been available for that long :)

Comment: Even if `:checked` was not available,  `$('#addressmatchedCheck')[0].checked` seems to be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you name your checkboxes like this, it works:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="addressmatchedCheck" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="rcnumbermatched" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="phonenumbercheck" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="idproofcheck" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="guarantoraddressmatchedCheck" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="guarantoridproofcheck" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="guarantorrelationshipCheck" checked="checked" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/DqdgC/